# Python/Apache "End of script output before headers" error when using from PIL import Image

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
#!/usr/local/bin python3

import cgi
import shutil
from PIL import Image

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("""
    <TITLE>CGI script ! Python</TITLE>
    <H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>
    Hello, world!
    """
    )
size = 128, 128

form_data = cgi.FieldStorage()
file_data = form_data['userfile'].value
file_name = form_data['userfile'].filename
file_type = form_data['userfile'].type
if file_type == 'image/jpeg':
    fp = open('./tmpmedia/' + file_name, 'wb')
    fp.write(file_data)
    fp.close()
    im = Image.open("./tmpmedia/9090.jpg")
    im.thumbnail(size)
    im.save("./tmpmedia/thumb.jpg", "JPEG")
else:
    print("Wrong type")
```

I think my issue has to do with my shebang/using python3. This script is ran when submitting and image on my webpage using an apache (xampp) server.
When i run the script locally with just the Image stuff (before the else and after fp.close()) it is successful. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't do this. user a proper web framework.

Comment: @e4c5 Meaning what exactly?

Comment: Using python as a pure CGI echoing out HTML is a lot of time and effort wasted that can be utilized for better things. Check out something like django or flask.